# Why is my variable not updating when I use a switch statement?

Tags: c, adventure

I am a student, and I am trying to make an adventure text game, without using arrays.
This code is a function, called by `main` (within another switch case statement). The problem is, the day doesn't update. It only updates when the code is included inline in `main`.

```
int getArea (int nArea) //area and day
{
    int nShisha, nBall,  nLolipop, nPepsi ;
    int nUser; //test variables
    int nPrice; // testing variable for price
    int naUser ;


    int nDay;
    nDay = 2;
    printf("Choose your Area\n");
    printf("1. Riyadh\n2. Jeddah\n3. Albaik\n4. Tazaj\n");
    printf("5. Go back\n");
    scanf("%d", &nArea);
    //nArea


    do{ //This is for the place
        switch (nArea)
        {
          case 1 : 
            printf("Riyadh\n");
            printf("Day %d of 15\n", nDay); 
            nDay ++;
            if (nDay == 16) {
                return 0;
            }   
            getPrice (&nShisha , &nBall, &nLolipop, &nPepsi ) ;// add charge soon
            break;
            
          case 2 :
            printf("Jeddah\n");
            printf("Day %d of 15\n", nDay);
            nDay ++;
            if (nDay == 16) {
                return 0;
            }   
            getPrice (&nShisha , &nBall, &nLolipop, &nPepsi ); // add charge soon
            break;
            
          case 3:
            printf("AlBaik\n");// add charge soon
            printf("Day %d of 15\n", nDay);
            nDay ++;
            if (nDay == 16) {
                return 0;
            }
            getPrice (&nShisha , &nBall, &nLolipop, &nPepsi );;
            break;
          case 4:
            printf("Tazaj\n");// add charge soon
            printf("Day %d of 15\n", nDay);
            nDay ++;
            if (nDay == 16) {
                return 0;
            }
            getPrice (&nShisha , &nBall, &nLolipop, &nPepsi );;
            break;


          default : printf("You have entered invalid!");
                    break;
        }
        //      printf("do you want to go to another place?\n");  //test code change later into better alternative
        scanf("%d", &nArea);

    }while (nArea!=0); //for area while
}
```

Can you guys please explain why is it not updating?

Comment: Note that function `getArea()` does not return any value at the end. Also, it ignores the value of `area` passed to it, which it overwrites, and the caller's variable which supplied its value will not be affected. Can't reproduce: `nDay` is incremented and the function returns when `nDay == 16`. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question text for conventional English word choice.  Please check that I have captured your intent, especially where I changed your original "I do it continuously" to "the code is included inline in `main`."

Comment: When you ask about "day", are you talking about variable `nDay`?  I don't see anything named "day".

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes im talking about the day nDay, as you see, for example. I a player want to travel to "Jeddah" the nDay does not increment for some reason. why is this? Do you think I need to use pointers for getArea()? example I use getArea(int* nday) so the nDay updates? any more tips?

Comment: im trying to make a text game like dope wars @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 1):

Per your clarification, you are talking about variable `nDay`.  In the code presented in the question, this variable is local to function `getArea()`.  I am confident that it is successfully updated in the function, but that will have no effect on any like-named variable in `main()` or elsewhere.  Those are different variables with the same name.  Since you describe factoring this code out of `main` into its own function, I am fairly confident that this is the nature of the problem.

If you want the function to modify a variable that is local to the caller, then the caller must pass a pointer to that variable, and the function must update the caller's variable indirectly, via the pointer.  For example, you might declare `getArea()` like this, instead:

```
int getArea(int area, int *nDay) {
    // ...
```

You would then also need to get rid of the other declaration of `nDay` inside `getArea()`:

```
int nDay;
```

, and all other appearances of `nDay` inside the function body would need to be replaced with `(*nDay)`.<sup>*</sup>

For its part, the caller would need to pass the appropriate pointer, something like:

```
int main(void) {
    int area, rval, nDay;
    // ...
    rval = getArea(area, &nDay);
    // ...
 }
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Technically, the parentheses are needed only in some cases, but they are harmless in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a variable in a user-defined function won't be updated in `main()` function as long as you are not returning it to to the `main()` function or the variable is a pointer that had been passed from the main function.
In your code, even though the variable `nDay` has been updated in the function `getArea`, the variable won't be updated in `main()` function if you don't return it. you can use

```
int getArea (int nArea)
{
    ...
    ...
    return nDay; // Only this value will be passed to the main() function. nothing else updated here will be passed.
}

int main()
{
    int x,y,z, nArea, nDay;//some variable that you declared. Assuming nDay is one of them
    ...
    ...
    nDay=getArea(nArea); //value returned from the function(which is "nDay" from getArea()) will be assigned to nDay
    ...
}
```

Also, I don't see any reason for passing `nArea` to `getArea()` as you are overwriting/taking new input(value) of `nArea` inside the function.
Note the `nDay` from `main()` and `nDay` from `getArea()` are actually different variable even though they have the same name.